# Обработка лога на Python

Tags: python

Есть лог событий, куда валится всякий мусор, например:

```
Fri Feb 21 04:50:53 2014
Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 13184

Private strand flush not complete

  Current log# 3 seq# 13183 mem# 0: /opt/oracle/admin/BITS/redolog/redo03.log

Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 13184

  Current log# 4 seq# 13184 mem# 0: /opt/oracle/admin/BITS/redolog/redo04.log

Fri Feb 21 04:51:02 2014

LNS: Standby redo logfile selected for thread 1 sequence 13184 for destination 

LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1

Fri Feb 21 05:00:53 2014

Thread 1 cannot allocate new log, sequence 13185

Private strand flush not complete

  Current log# 4 seq# 13184 mem# 0: /opt/ora/admin/Bнн/redolog/redo04.log

Thread 1 advanced to log sequence 13185

  Current log# 3 seq# 13185 mem# 0: /opt/ora/admin/Bнн/redolog/redo03.log

Fri Feb 21 05:00:57 2014

LNS: Standby redo logfile selected for thread 1 sequence 13185 for destination 

LOG_ARCHIVE_DEST_1
```

В нём содержатся записи, которые нужны и интересны, например:

```
ORA-0155 caused by SQL statement below (SQL ID: 39c4440, Query Duration=13923299 sec, SCN: 0x0001.48500a):
SELECT * FROM RELATIONAL("BILL"."REQUEST")
The value (30) of MAXTRANS parameter ignored.
kupprdp: master process DM00 started with pid=100, OS id=11330
         to execute - SYS.KUPM$MCP.MAIN('SYS_EXPORT_FULL_06', 'SYS', 'KUPC$C_1_201402210646', 'KUPC$S_1_2014021064146', 0);
kupprdp: worker process DW01 started with worker id=1, pid=109, OS id=11332
         to execute - SYS.KUPW$WORKER.MAIN('SYS_ERT_FULL_06', 'SYS');
ALTER SYSTEM SET undo_retention=90 SCOPE=BOTH;
```

Сейчас я просто фильтрую все мусорные строки через оператор `in`, но остаётся проблема с тем, что даты так не отфильтровать.

Вот примерная реализация того, что получилось у меня:

```
with open(log_filename, 'r') as log_file:
    for line in log_file.readlines():
        if 'LNS: Standby redo logfile selected for thread' not in line: 
            if '...' not in line:
                ...
                    print(line)
```

Есть ли пример решения подобной задачи фильтрации вместе с датами?

Answer (score 1):

В вашем случае известно, какие строки нужно отбросить, но неизвестно, какие должны остаться.

Подойдёт реализация на основе "черного списка" (т.е. отбрасываем всё, что можем; то, что не отбросили - нужное).

У вас есть два варианта проверок: простые (где можно воспользоваться оператором `in`) и сложные (где требуются регулярные выражения).

Предлагаю сгруппировать простые и сложные проверки следующим образом:

```
# В этом списке собираются подстроки для проверки через in
bad_line_parts = [
    'Standby redo logfile selected for thread',
    ...
]
```

Более сложные проверки действительно может быть удобнее реализовывать через регулярные выражения. В вашем случае, с датой можно использовать довольно простое выражение с малым шансом пропустить что-то лишнее (и с малым шансом не пропустить что-то важное):

```
import re
bad_reg_exprs = [
    re.compile('[A-Z][a-z]{2} [A-Z][a-z]{2} \d{1,2} \d\d:\d\d:\d\d \d{4}'),
    ...  # здесь дополнить другими регулярными выражениями, если потребуется
]
```

Фильтрацию можно будет написать теперь таким образом:

```
def is_fine_line(line):
    return (not any(bad_line_part in line 
                    for bad_line_part in bad_line_parts) and 
            not any(bad_reg_expr.match(line) 
                    for bad_reg_expr in bad_reg_exprs))

with open(log_filename, 'r') as log_file:
    for line in log_file.readlines():
        if is_fine_line(line):
            print(line)
```

При желании можно расширить фунцию `is_fine_line` проверками типа "белого списка" аналогичным образом.

Таким образом, из основной функции вынесена функциональность, ответственная за фильтрацию строк, что должно повысить читаемость.

Также, появилась возможность использования новой функции в качестве фильтрующего условия:

```
filtered_lines = (line for line in log_file if is_fine_line(line))
```

Comment: лучше воспользоваться awk, синтаксис более лаконичный

Answer (score -1):

Надо использовать RegEXP